# Impact of shrinking ldf file after restoring full backup

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore, transaction-log

What is the use of data in `.ldf`(log) file after restoring a full backup. I am planning to shrink the log files after restoring the full backup in my dev server.

Is there any side effect for this ?

Comment: Are you going to put your db in simple mode afterwards?

Comment: The log file stores information about changes made in SQL Server. It has major role to play when restoring full backup because a full backup may include [few amount of transaction log](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/more-on-how-much-transaction-log-a-full-backup-includes/) and if that is missed recovery is not possible. You may shrink log file after restoring and this will not lead to any data loss but DONT make it a habit.

Comment: @StijnWynants - No it will be `FULL` same as my Live server.

Comment: @Shanky - The server in which am restoring is only for development, at any case there will not be a need to recover data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any side effect for this ?

No, not really. The worst thing that could happen is the log file grows again, given this is a dev server that's not a problem. Worst case is the log takes up all available space and your db goes into read-only... which is easily rectifiable and downtime is fine as it's a dev server.

Shrink away.